# C++ neural network for multiple inputs

Tags: c++, neural-network

I am building a neural network using C++ with just one hidden layer. My neural network takes 2 input and produces 1 output, with bias nodes in the first two layers. When I train the network with just one type of data (say input=(0,0), desired output=1), the network trains well. But when I train with two types (say (0,0)->1, (1,0)->0), the network performs very poorly. What I did was to loop

- set desired input = (0,0), set desired output = 1
- forward propagate
- calculate error
- back propagate
- set desired input = (1,0), set desired output = 0
- forward propagate
- calculate error
- back propagate

Here is an excerpt of the code

```
vector<double> input0, output0;
input0.push_back(0);
input0.push_back(0);
output0.push_back(1);

vector<double> input1, output1;
input1.push_back(1);
input1.push_back(0);
output1.push_back(0);

for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
  n->setUserInput(input0);
  n->setIdealOutputs(output0);
  n->feedForward();
  n->backPropagate();

  n->setUserInput(input1);
  n->setIdealOutputs(output1);
  n->feedForward();
  n->backPropagate();
}
```

The network does well when I just perform one of the two chunks in the loop. Surprisingly, if I have two types of input, both having the same output, the network performs well. This puzzles me. Is there anything wrong with the way I train the network with two types of data?

Comment: Could you include some code as well?

Comment: the code is quite long though, which part of it should I include? I am pretty sure the back propagation and forward propagation are implemented correctly

Comment: Include the part you think will help the developers to reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you write test cases for your code? If the whole code is too big, then test smaller parts and try to find the spot that does not produce the output you expect, that might make a good [mcve] you can post here. Unfortunatly without code we'd need a magic crystal ball to help you

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the way I train the network. The network does well when I just fee one type of input & output, that is, in every loop I train with the same input and same output.